# How to get correct seaborn histogram?

Tags: seaborn

Why when I use command like this (exmaple data):

```
col = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
data = {"a": [4], "b": [1], "c": [8], "d": [0]}
seaborn.displot(data, x=col)
```

I get

[hist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOyLA.png)

I don't think that's what it should look like. Any advices?

Comment: But it is correct. Each letter occurs once in your data. Read up on the difference between a barplot and a histogram. If you want the value 4 for "a" in a histogram, then you need to have 4 rows of "a" in your data.

Comment: okey, I will check. Thanks for help! @cripcate

Comment: Maybe you want `sns.barplot(x=col, y=[data[c][0] for c in col])`?

Comment: That was exactly what I need, thanks! @JohanC